# How to substitute values in a MAP to string template in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a string with placeholders. I want to substitute values for that placeholders and those values are stored in a MAP (dictionary). I am using following code

```
from string import Template

values = {'what': 'surreal', 'punctuation': 'is'}
t = Template(" Hello, $what world $punctuation One of Python least-used functions is ")
t.substitute(values)

print t
```

This want give me correct results

My output should be:

```
Hello, surreal world is One of Python least-used functions is
```

Could you give me your opinion on how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [string format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) for your example:

```
values = {'what': 'surreal', 'punctuation': 'is'}
template=" Hello, {what} world {punctuation} One of Python least-used functions is "
t = template.format(**values)
print(t)
# Hello, surreal world is One of Python least-used functions is
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a template engine like `Genshi`.
This gives you more flexibility and well they are designed to do this :-)

Genshi example based on http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/0.6.x/templates.html:

```python
>>> from genshi.template import TextTemplate
>>> tmpl = TextTemplate('Hello, ${dict.what} world ${dict.punctuation} One of Python least-used functions is')
>>> stream = tmpl.generate(dict={'what':'surreal', 'punctuation':'is'})
>>> print(stream)
Hello, surreal world is One of Python least-used functions is
```

It's also easy to create some markup by using `genshi.template.MarkupTemplate`.

I also recommend to separate the template from the code, you can use file-like objects for `TextTemplate` or `MarkupTemplate`.